# Finding array element's position whitin the element itself in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Цhat is the most effective way to find an element position within an array, if we got access to the element itself?

```
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    arr[i] = {test: Math.floor(Math.random() * 101)}
}
var test = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * 11)];
```

Now how can I get the position of the element that `test` refer to?

Comment: May be in this way     var pos=Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);

Answer (score 1):

I'd just store the position when generating it here, like this:

```
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    arr[i] = {test: Math.floor(Math.random() * 101)}
}
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
var test = arr[index];
//index is the position
```

Comment: Isn't that memory intensive? (assuming I have a large multi-dimensional array where each cell is occupied)

Comment: @GZaidman - I wouldn't say so...the alternative is of searching via `.indexOf()` is much more CPU intensive, when you already know the result.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the random generation is just an example.

Now if you've got a **reference** to an element and want to find out its index you can use [`Array.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method. It's a new feature so not all browsers support it natively, but it's easy to implement. A bare-bone solution would look like:

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
  Array.prototype.indexOf = function (searchElement) {
    var len = this.length >>> 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      if (searchElement === this[i]) return i;
    }
    return -1;
  };
}
```

Now you can use it as:

```
index = array.indexOf(elem)    // index from an element reference
examp = [5,8,12,5].indexOf(12) // 2
```

​